# Set a specific input fields

Tags: templates, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to make various specific input fields and I followed [this tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaFormHelpers).

I'm using Play 2 with Java in Eclipse.

The problem I'm facing is this line :

```
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myFieldConstructorTemplate.f) }
```

1. If I define it oustide my template (outside `@main("Title"){}`), It can't find `FieldConstructor.`
2. If I define it inside my template, `@implicitField` generate a compilation error :

> not found: value implicitField.

How can I do?

I'd prefer to define a package since I will have many inputs (text, radio, checkboxes, etc). I like how it has [been done here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper) but I have no idea how to make multiple helpers like that that would be automatically used in my templates.

Thank you for your help, I appreciate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's quite common ... mistake :) you need to import helper package first in your template:

```
@import helper._
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myFieldConstructorTemplate.f) }

@main("Title"){
    ....
}
```

Comment: How right! Thanks! And do you know if this will be automatically adapted to all my inputs fields ? (say I made an inputText, inputPassword, inputRadio, etc)?